# What's the difference between a failed job and a job that has completed exceptionally?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html) seem to be saying they're the same.  Is that a correct interpretation?

> A coroutine job is said to complete exceptionally when its body throws an exception; a CompletableJob is completed exceptionally by calling CompletableJob.completeExceptionally. An exceptionally completed job is cancelled and the corresponding exception becomes the cancellation cause of the job.

> Normal cancellation of a job is distinguished from its failure by the type of this exception that caused its cancellation. A coroutine that threw CancellationException is considered to be cancelled normally. If a cancellation cause is a different exception type, then the job is considered to have failed. When a job has failed, then its parent gets cancelled with the exception of the same type, thus ensuring transparency in delegating parts of the job to its children.

Comment: Basically a tristate. [SUCCESS, CANCELLED, FAILED (exceptionally)]. Failed could also include cancelled, e.g. if cancelled from within, due to an expected data-misconfiguration or thelike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understood about [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) is the following things :

- You have 2 types of jobs

  - Ones created by a launch that are **Coroutine Jobs**

    - Behavior of that jobs : when the code block given as parameter of launch is done, the job is complete
  - Ones created by the Job constructors that are  **CompletableJob**

    - Behavior of that Job : complete when *complete* method is called

And now about the tricky part is about the end before completion of a job

## Normal cancellation

- a job is cancelled (the documentation says normal cancellation)

  - implies that

    - the job execution continue until the next suspension
    - all children continue until the next suspension (and then move to the completed state)
    - and when all that done the job move to the cancelled state
    - Parent job receives the given exception and can managed it with *invokeOnCompletion*
    - the parent is not affected by his children normal cancellations (it is not completed and not cancelled)
  - we can can cancel a job

    - for a *CompletableJob* : call [completeExceptionnally with a parameter that extends CancellationException or a CancellationException object](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-job/complete-exceptionally.html)
    - for a *Coroutine Job* : call [cancel that waits a CancellationException parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/cancel.html)
    - Or we can also [throw a CancellationException](https://pl.kotl.in/46OujjKsI) (but the job is immediately cancelled, code until the next suspension is not executed)

https://pl.kotl.in/HpSW-5Jgd?theme=darcula

## Failure

- a job failed means that all the treatments attached to it failed

  - children, parents, cousins move to the Cancelling state
  - we can fail a job

    - for a *CompletableJob* : call completeExceptionnally with a parameter that **NOT** extends CancellationException
    - throw an exception that **NOT** extends CancellationException

https://pl.kotl.in/VzV1md3Wc

## Answer

Then about your question :

- a failed job is the job had an exception that was not a CancellationException (second case)
- a completed exceptionally job is the job that has been failed or has been cancelled (can be the first or the second case)

https://pl.kotl.in/miTSI972L

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I noticed there's an error in the second code snippet https://pl.kotl.in/KNjyynfvw.  "not printed as child failed" is actually printed when the code is run.  I think this happens because the Job of the first `launch` in the snippet isn't a child of the enclosing `runBlocking`'s Job.  That's because that `launch` is explicitly provided a `Job` instance.   This is a fixed version of the snippet - https://pl.kotl.in/VzV1md3Wc.

Comment: You’re right. In fact a duplicate the code and forgot to remove the last println. Thanks to pointed me that. I put your fix in the answer

Answer (score 0):

A job that has thrown an exception of any type is considered to be "completed exceptionally".  The job is further identified as "failed" or "normally cancelled", depending on the type of exception thrown.  If the exception thrown is a `CancellationException` then the job is "normally cancelled".  If the exception is any other type, then the job is "failed".